# Can jquery animate the css background property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that you can `.animate() background-image` with jQuery.  But can you `.animate()` `background: url(myImageURL) top center repeat-y` ?

EDIT

The purpose of the function is to animate from `background: undeclared` to `background: url(images/red_curtain.jpg) top center repeat-y` :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860749/jquery-animation-background-image-swap

Comment: @SLaks - it would animate from `background: undeclared` to  `background: url(images/red_curtain.jpg) top center repeat-y` :)

Comment: What would it look like?

Comment: @SLaks - here is the production URL: http://valeriaentertainment.com.s66112.gridserver.com ... goal is this: delay background-image display until after page load, then fade the image in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the background into a separate element, then `fadeIn()` that element.

However, it is not possible to fade in a background directly; CSS does not allow you to adjust the opacity of an image.

Answer (score 3):

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/ - might help :-)